# How to bind json data to screen with tpl config?

Tags: json, rest, extjs, data-binding, openweathermap

I'm working on Sencha's [Admin Dashboard](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard) sample and trying to customize '**Weather**' panel.

I've created a JSON format url with OpenWeatherMap's [Current weather data](https://openweathermap.org/current) API. The thing I can't bind JSON data to Weather panel with `tpl` config. I've created a ViewModel and called it within Component but it did not worked as well.

Here is the component class;

```
Ext.define('OWeb.view.dashboard.Weather', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'weather',

    baseCls: 'weather-panel',
    border: false,
    height: 80,

    store: {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Antalya,TR&appid=9b59049894d42af608baf69f869b9ace&units=metric',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    },

    tpl: '<div class="weather-image-container"><img src="resources/img/{icon}" alt="{weather.description}"/></div>'+
         '<div class="weather-details-container">' +
            '<div>{main.temp}&#176;</div>' +
            '<div>{weather.main}</div>' +
         '</div>'
});
```

And this is [link](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Antalya,TR&appid=9b59049894d42af608baf69f869b9ace&units=metric) for JSON data which returns via OpenWeatherMap and snippet;

```
{
     "coord": {
         "lon": 30.72,
         "lat": 36.77
     },
     "weather": [{
         "id": 800,
         "main": "Clear",
         "description": "clear sky",
         "icon": "01d"
     }],
     "base": "stations",
     "main": {
         "temp": 25,
         "pressure": 1015,
         "humidity": 23,
         "temp_min": 25,
         "temp_max": 25
     },
     "visibility": 10000,
     "wind": {
         "speed": 5.7,
         "deg": 320
     },
     "clouds": {
         "all": 0
     },
     "dt": 1507184400,
     "sys": {
         "type": 1,
         "id": 6028,
         "message": 0.0025,
         "country": "TR",
         "sunrise": 1507175759,
         "sunset": 1507217657
     },
     "id": 323776,
     "name": "Antalya",
     "cod": 200
 }
```

Thanks, any advice is welcome.

---

**UPDATE**

I've found [this post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?62854-Ext-Template-with-JSon-Data-Store) and I tried same thing; extend from `Ext.DataView`, setting proxy type `jsonp` and using `itemTpl` config. Now I can bind to JSON data but only can displaying `{main.temp}`. Any idea please?

```
Ext.define('OWeb.view.dashboard.Weather', {
    //extend: 'Ext.Component',
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    xtype: 'weather',

    baseCls: 'weather-panel',
    border: false,
    height: 80,

    store: {
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Antalya,TR&appid=9b59049894d42af608baf69f869b9ace&units=metric',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    },

    itemTpl: '<div class="weather-image-container"><img src="{weather.icon}" alt="{weather.description}"/></div>'+
         '<div class="weather-details-container">' +
            '<div>{main.temp}&#176;</div>' +
            '<div>{weather.description}</div>' +
         '</div>'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the points below to understand this.

1. `Ext.Component` class does not work with store because of which your code was not working. You could have created the store elsewhere and then retrieved the data from store and set the `data` property of the component to it. (Note that for `Ext.Component`, the `tpl` property works with `data` property:

   var data = store.getData();

   component.setData(data);
2. `jsonP` proxy is needed only when you need to fetch data from a different domain.
3. If you are getting data in a store then better option is to extend your class from `Ext.DataView` because it works with store.
4. The values were not properly showing in the template because **weather** property was an array of objects and we needed something like `weather[0].icon`. So for this, Model was required with fields properly mapped.(Look at the `mapping` property.)
5. I have created a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27rl) for your code. Image is not showing because url is not returning any image. Rest is working. Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Dear @Amita thanks a lot for those useful statements. I've refactored the panel according your statements. Now it works very well.

Comment: Most Welcome :)